# List Files: Backend Error (No error code) Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

we've built a web app that automatically indexes and saves email attachments directly to Google Drive based on user-defined business rules. We're seeing failures when syncing some Google Drive accounts and can't figure out what the problem is.

This is the error:

> List Files Error: Backend Error 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/app/models/cloud_account/google_drive.rb:299:in 'list_files' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/app/models/cloud_account/google_drive.rb:220:in 'do_discover_files' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/app/models/cloud_account/base.rb:304:in 'discover_files' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/app/workers/worker/file_synchronizer.rb:10:in 'perform' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:45:in 'block (3 levels) in 
>   process' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:109:in 'call' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:109:in 'block in in 
>   voke' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/lib/sidekiq_repeat_jobs/middleware/server/repeat_jobs.rb:36:in 'call' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:111:in 'block in in 
>   voke' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/timeout.rb:14:in 'cal 
>   l' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:111:in 'block in in 
>   voke' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in 
>   'call' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:111:in 'block in in 
>   voke' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:49:in ' 
>   call' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:111:in 'block in in 
>   voke' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in 'blo 
>   ck in call' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:22:in 'with_context' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in 'call 
>   ' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:111:in 'block in in 
>   voke' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:114:in 'call' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:114:in 'invoke' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:44:in 'block (2 levels) in 
>   process' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:80:in 'stats' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sidekiq-2.6.5/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:43:in 'block in process' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.4/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:23:in 'call' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.4/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:23:in 'public_send' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.4/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:23:in 'dispatch' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.4/lib/celluloid/future.rb:18:in 'block in initiali 
>   ze' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.4/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:48:in 'call' 
>   /mnt/opt/openera/current/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/celluloid-0.12.4/lib/celluloid/internal_pool.rb:48:in 'block in c 
>   reate'

UPDATE: Here is the actual code from our senior dev.

dev here (ffoeg) adding actual code invoked:

```rb
def list_files
 pageToken = nil
 params = {'maxResults' => 65535, 'q' => 'trashed = false'}
 files = [] 
 drive = session.discovered_api("drive", "v2")
 while true do
   call_params = pageToken.blank? ? params : params.merge('pageToken' => pageToken)
   result = session.execute(api_method: drive.files.list, parameters: call_params)
   if result.status == 200
     files += result.data.items
     break if result.data['nextPageToken'].blank?
     pageToken = result.data['nextPageToken']
   else 
     raise "List Files Error: #{result.data['error']['message']}"
   end  
 end  
 files
end
```

UPDATING AGAIN:

We updated our code to get the exact error - here it is:

```
List Files Error: {"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"backendError", 
"message"=>"Backend Error"}], "code"=>503, "message"=>"Backend Error"}
```

Comment: Can you also add your code? Does it always fail with some users and succeed with others? Does the same call work if you try again? Are you handling errors as explained at https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors ?

Comment: It doesn't fail with all users - it does succeed with most. This error seems to be specific to some user accounts. Once it fails with a particular account, it continues to fail no matter how many times we make that call.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't realize "Enter" would submit the comment. Since we're not getting a particular error code - we've been unable to handle this error as explained on Google dev site - I'll grab the code for the call we are making and post it.

Comment: so now, despite our friendly 'editors', the code in question has been added above

Comment: Updated with precise code returned with the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value of maxResults. It is *far* too large and will cause the request to time out. Unfortunately, a "safe" value is very small, about ~200 results per page. You can go larger, but results will vary based on the user. Users with smaller corpuses will probably work fine with larger page sizes, but people with larger corpuses appear to be more sensitive.  Well, at least based on some very quick/informal testing on a few of my accounts.

FWIW, I remember things working better with larger page sizes. Will check if anything changed that might constrain things more than expected.

Comment: Thank you for checking this! We'll do some testing with various account sizes to see if we can pinpoint how many results generate an error.